# build a wcf project with msbuild

Tags: wcf, msbuild

I'm trying to build an WCf project woth my custom MSBuild script.

In the PropertyGroup I have

```
 <DeployServicesRoot>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(Configuration)\Services</DeployServicesRoot>
 <IntermediateRoot>$(DeployServicesRoot)\obj</IntermediateRoot>
 <DevelopmentSymbols>DEVELOPMENT;DEBUG</DevelopmentSymbols>
```

in ItemGroup

```
<Solution Include="..\..\src\WCFProj\WCFProj.csproj" />
<DeployFiles Include="$(DeployServicesRoot)\**\*.*" />
<IntermediateFiles Include="$(IntermediateRoot)\**\*.*" />
```

and the MSBuild task:

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(Solution)" Properties="DefineConstants=$(DevelopmentSymbols);OutputPath=$(DeployServicesRoot)\bin\;BaseIntermediateOutputPath=$(IntermediateRoot)\Services\;DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package"/>
```

The problem is that, the deployed package is located in the obj subdirectory, not in the bin. In the bin there are only the *.dll files, no WCF *.svc and transformed web.config. Is there any available additional parameter to set to the MSBuild task the output package path? I know I can do it with the Copy Task, but I'm curius is there any other (easier?) solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MSBuild properties I had to add _PackageTempDir=$(DeployServicesRoot)" after the DeployTarget.